# How to remove SQL Server transaction replication errors without restarting the full process. we have around 1 billion

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, replication, large-data

We have setup transaction replication on around 40 tables. Which works fine for small tables except the large ones.

We have around 1 billion rows in a table and the replication takes a lot of time. During the first phase of snapshot creation and bulk data movement if there is an error the whole process needs to run again. Is there are a way to sync only the remaining records after fixing the error.

The error we get is

> The process could not bulk copy into table 'xxx'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20037)
> Get help: [link to help/MSSQL_REPL20037]
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> To obtain an error file with details on the errors encountered when initializing the subscribing table, execute the bcp command that appears below. Consult the BOL for more information on the bcp utility and its supported options. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20253)
> Get help: [link to help/20253]
> bcp "xxx" in "xxx" -e "errorfile" -t"\n<x$3>\n" -r"\n<,@g>\n" -m10000 -SAZQC1W -T -w (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20253)
> Get help: [link to help/20253]

The problem is that we have the same rows in the destination table but replication truncates the destination table and syncs it again. What's the best way around this problem?

We have setup the transaction replication between two servers which is working as expected for all small tables, but for large table we have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers for Error 20253 show it may be caused by SSMS 18 BCP incompatibility with older versions of SQL Server.  Try with SSMS 17.
It may also be due to schema mismatch between publisher and subscriber.

[SQL Server Transactional replication - The process could not bulk copy into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39166975/sql-server-transactional-replication-the-process-could-not-bulk-copy-into)

Replication will truncate and load the BCP statements during reinitialization unless you initialize the subscriber manually by ETL the publisher tables over yourself, or initialize the subscriber from backup:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-transactional-subscription-from-a-backup?view=sql-server-ver16

For the automated snapshot initialization method, ensure compression is enabled for the bcp files and your network and share location is a reliable server:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-options?view=sql-server-ver16

Ensure the SQL service account has its permissions directly granted on the share folder rather than an AD group.

Similar
[SQL Server transactional replication for very large tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344684/sql-server-transactional-replication-for-very-large-tables?rq=4)